# how can I access functions from another program into my new program

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a program that is related to another program, so how can I access the individual functions from my previous program and work with them as required, I know you are suppose to import that program but what to do after that.
The program that I import how can I use functions from it.

Comment: After you have imported them, you… call them? What exactly is the issue you're dealing with? Importing a function from another module, or something more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be better if you write code.
I assume your 1st code is code1.py and you want to use fun1 from it in code2.py.
Put them in same directory . . .

Use:

```
import code1
code1.fun1()
```

Or

```
from code1 import *
fun1()
```

Note: 2nd method is not recommended.

Comment: Please don't advocate wildcard imports. Read the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) for details.

Comment: I agree with PEP style.

@Matthias
I think his code is very basic one.

And importing * will not have big drawback.

Any way, your recommendation is right.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import it from another folder you should also try to use os.chdir().
But mostly you can use either import * to import all of the functions or just import and then the functions you want to import.